# Pandas cumsum only when ID are not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a','b','a','c','b','a','c','b','a','c'], 'Value': [3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1]})
```

Now, I want to get the culmulative sum of *Value* base on the value of *ID* for all the previous *ID* that are not equals to the current *ID*. My difficulty is how to dynamically read each value of *ID* and compare it with the *ID* in previous rows.

What I expected to get is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a','b','a','c','b','a','c','b','a','c'], 'Value': [3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1],'Sum':[0,3,2,8,7,8,16,14,14,24]})
```

I tried to use np.where and groupby, which does not help.
In similar questions, a clear condition for the cumsum is provided such as greater than 5, or boolen == True, which is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with cumulative sum per groups by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Sum'] = df['Value'].cumsum().sub(df.groupby('ID')['Value'].cumsum())
print (df)
  ID  Value  Sum
0  a      3    0
1  b      2    3
2  a      3    2
3  c      1    8
4  b      5    7
5  a      3    8
6  c      4   16
7  b      2   14
8  a      6   14
9  c      1   24
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the normal [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and subtract the [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) to remove the self-ID counts:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Value'].cumsum().sub(df.groupby('ID')['Value'].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
  ID  Value  Sum
0  a      3    0
1  b      2    3
2  a      3    2
3  c      1    8
4  b      5    7
5  a      3    8
6  c      4   16
7  b      2   14
8  a      6   14
9  c      1   24
```

Intermediates:

```
  ID  Value  Sum  cumsum  groupby.cumsum
0  a      3    0       3               3
1  b      2    3       5               2
2  a      3    2       8               6
3  c      1    8       9               1
4  b      5    7      14               7
5  a      3    8      17               9
6  c      4   16      21               5
7  b      2   14      23               9
8  a      6   14      29              15
9  c      1   24      30               6
```

#### median

This one is more complex. The strategy is to build an intermediate numpy array with one column per unique ID. For each one we mask the values of the ID and compute an `expanding.median`:

```
a1 = df[['ID']].to_numpy()
a2 = df['ID'].unique()
m = a1==a2

df['median'] = (
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[['Value']].to_numpy(),
                       len(a2), axis=1),
             index=df.index)
  .mask(m)
  .expanding().median()
  .where(m).stack()
  .droplevel(1)
)
```

Output:

```
  ID  Value  median
0  a      3     NaN
1  b      2     3.0
2  a      3     2.0
3  c      1     3.0
4  b      5     3.0
5  a      3     2.0
6  c      4     3.0
7  b      2     3.0
8  a      6     2.0
9  c      1     3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was quick. Just a follow-up question, what if I want to get the median value for previous rows with a different ID instead of the cumsum? Thanks!

Comment: @Syhaa It's more complex as the median computation requires knowledge of all points, we can't use a shortcut like for the cumsum. I added an approach for that.